# How to get all possible indices of a multidimensional array without memory errors?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, indices

I would like to sample a 26 dimensional space with say 10 points in every direction. This means that there are in total 10**26 samples, but I'll discard more than 99.9999... %. Using python, this immediately leads to memory errors.

A first naive approach is to use nested loops:

```
p = list(range(10))
for p1 in p:
    for p2 in p:
        ...
```

However, Python has an in-built maximum on the amount of nested loops: 20.

A better approach would be to use the numpy.indices command:

```
import numpy as np
dimensions = (10,)*26
indices = np.indices(*dimensions)
```

This fails with an "array too big" message because Numpy can't fit all 10**26 indices in memory. Understandable.

My final approach was to use an iterator, hoping this didn't need more memory:

```
import numpy as np
dimensions = (10,)*26
for index in np.ndindex(*dimensions):
    # do something with index
```

However, this ALSO fails with an "array too big" message, since under the hood Numpy still tries to create a dense array.

Does anybody else have a better approach?

Thanks!
Tom

EDIT: The "array too big" message is probably because 10**26 is larger than the maximum value an Int64 can store. If you could tell Numpy to store the size as an Int128, that might circumvent the ValueError at least. It'll still require almost 20GB to store all the indices as Int64 though ...

Comment: Could you iteratively update a number of distributions, rather than sampling precisely? Alternatively ```scipy.sparse```?

Comment: The interpolation scheme I use afterwards requires a regular grid unfortunately.

Comment: "However, Python has an in-built maximum on the amount of nested loops: " really??

Answer (score 0):

So far, this is the solution that I've found:

```
class IndicesGenerator:
    def __init__(self, nbDimensions, nbSamplesPerDimension):
        self.nbDimensions = nbDimensions
        self.nbSamplesPerDimension = nbSamplesPerDimension
    def getNbDimensions(self):
        return self.nbDimensions
    def getNbSamplesPerDimension(self):
        return self.nbSamplesPerDimension
    def getIndices(self):
        d = self.getNbDimensions()
        N = self.getNbSamplesPerDimension()
        # create indices
        indices = []
        prevIndex = None
        for i in range(d):
            newIndex = Index(maxValue=N-1, prev=prevIndex)
            indices.append(newIndex)
            prevIndex = newIndex
        lastIndex = indices[-1]
        while True:
            try:
                yield list(map(lambda index: index.getValue(), indices))
                lastIndex.increment()
            except RuntimeError:
                break

class Index:
    def __init__(self, maxValue, prev=None):
        assert prev is None or isinstance(prev, Index)
        assert isinstance(maxValue, int)
        self.prev = prev
        self.value = 0
        self.maxValue = maxValue
    def getPrevious(self):
        return self.prev
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value
    def setValue(self, value):
        assert isinstance(value, int)
        self.value = value
    def getMaximumValue(self):
        return self.maxValue
    def increment(self):
        if self.getValue() == self.getMaximumValue():
            # increment previous and set the current one to zero
            if self.getPrevious() is None:
                # the end is reached, so raise an error
                raise RuntimeError
            else:
                self.setValue(0)
                self.getPrevious().increment()
        else:
            self.setValue(self.getValue()+1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    nbIndices = 0
    d = 3
    N = 5
    start = time.time()
    for indices in IndicesGenerator(nbDimensions=d, nbSamplesPerDimension=N).getIndices():
        # print(indices)
        nbIndices += 1
    assert nbIndices == N**d
    end = time.time()
    print("Nb indices generated: ", nbIndices)
    print("Computation time: ", round(end-start,2), "s.")
```

It's not fast for large dimensions but at least it works without memory errors.